# Converting 2 select clauses into 1 select

Tags: sql-server, join, select, union

I'm making a "bom" list entry into the "materials" table.

I bring the materials defined for the product group to the grid so that users do not forget the relevant material.

Users define through this template.

But they add extra material (other than the group template) if they want.

If there is a record in the second select statement; I want to not show the record in 1 select statement.

I understand from the lvl column that this record should be crushed in the second select clause. (Definition has been made for template numbered 2)

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[materials](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [productCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [description] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [usageQauntity] [float] NULL,
    [process] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [vendor] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lvl] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_materials] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [groupCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [unit] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [price] [float] NULL,
    [minStock] [int] NULL,
    [maxStock] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[materials] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (1, N'pencil', N'paint chemical', 0.15, N'1', N'ABC', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (2, N'pencil', N'pen inside', 1, N'1', N'DEF', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (4, N'pencil', N'cover', 1, N'2', N'GHD', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (5, N'pencil', N'brand label', 1, N'0', N'ABC', 4)
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (6, N'lp', N'top eraser', 1, N'0', N'', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (7, N'lp', N'DEF brand pencil inside', 1, N'1', N'DEF', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (8, N'eraser', N'chemical', 1, N'0', N'ABC', 4)
INSERT [dbo].[materials] ([id], [productCode], [description], [usageQauntity], [process], [vendor], [lvl]) VALUES (9, N'eraser', N'brand label', 1, N'0', N'ABC', 4)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[materials] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[product] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([id], [code], [name], [groupCode], [unit], [price], [minStock], [maxStock]) VALUES (1, N'lp', N'lead pencil', N'pencil', N'piece', 15, 1000, 2000)
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([id], [code], [name], [groupCode], [unit], [price], [minStock], [maxStock]) VALUES (2, N'bp', N'ball-point pen', N'pencil', N'piece', 25, 2000, 3000)
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([id], [code], [name], [groupCode], [unit], [price], [minStock], [maxStock]) VALUES (3, N'sp', N'stylographic pen', N'pencil', N'piece', 50, 1000, 2000)
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([id], [code], [name], [groupCode], [unit], [price], [minStock], [maxStock]) VALUES (4, N'me', N'Magnetic eraser', N'eraser', N'piece', 30, 1000, 1500)
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([id], [code], [name], [groupCode], [unit], [price], [minStock], [maxStock]) VALUES (5, N'se', N'Soft Eraser', N'eraser', N'piece', 20, 1000, 2000)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[product] OFF
```

```
13 rows affected
```

```
select * from product
select * from materials
```

| id | code | name | groupCode | unit | price | minStock | maxStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lp | lead pencil | pencil | piece | 15 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 2 | bp | ball-point pen | pencil | piece | 25 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 3 | sp | stylographic pen | pencil | piece | 50 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 4 | me | Magnetic eraser | eraser | piece | 30 | 1000 | 1500 |
| 5 | se | Soft Eraser | eraser | piece | 20 | 1000 | 2000 |

| id | productCode | description | usageQauntity | process | vendor | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pencil | paint chemical | 0.15 | 1 | ABC | 1 |
| 2 | pencil | pen inside | 1 | 1 | DEF | 2 |
| 4 | pencil | cover | 1 | 2 | GHD | 3 |
| 5 | pencil | brand label | 1 | 0 | ABC | 4 |
| 6 | lp | top eraser | 1 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 7 | lp | DEF brand pencil inside | 1 | 1 | DEF | 2 |
| 8 | eraser | chemical | 1 | 0 | ABC | 4 |
| 9 | eraser | brand label | 1 | 0 | ABC | 4 |

```
select p.id,p.code,m2.*
from product p
left join materials m2 on m2.productCode=p.groupCode
where p.code='lp'

select  p.id,p.code,m1.*
from product p
left join materials m1 on m1.productCode=p.code
where p.code='lp'
```

| id | code | id | productCode | description | usageQauntity | process | vendor | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lp | 1 | pencil | paint chemical | 0.15 | 1 | ABC | 1 |
| 1 | lp | 2 | pencil | pen inside | 1 | 1 | DEF | 2 |
| 1 | lp | 4 | pencil | cover | 1 | 2 | GHD | 3 |
| 1 | lp | 5 | pencil | brand label | 1 | 0 | ABC | 4 |

| id | code | id | productCode | description | usageQauntity | process | vendor | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lp | 6 | lp | top eraser | 1 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1 | lp | 7 | lp | DEF brand pencil inside | 1 | 1 | DEF | 2 |

```
--test: Since lvl=2 is defined in the product, materials.id=2 should not appear.
select  p.id,p.code,m1.*
from product p
left join materials m1 on (m1.productCode=p.code or m1.productCode=p.groupCode)
where p.code='lp'
```

| id | code | id | productCode | description | usageQauntity | process | vendor | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lp | 1 | pencil | paint chemical | 0.15 | 1 | ABC | 1 |
| 1 | lp | 2 | pencil | pen inside | 1 | 1 | DEF | 2 |
| 1 | lp | 4 | pencil | cover | 1 | 2 | GHD | 3 |
| 1 | lp | 5 | pencil | brand label | 1 | 0 | ABC | 4 |
| 1 | lp | 6 | lp | top eraser | 1 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1 | lp | 7 | lp | DEF brand pencil inside | 1 | 1 | DEF | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t3Z_6u92)

Comment: Why in the world can you have a `ProductCode` that is also a `GroupCode`?  That's a pretty large deficiency in the data model (not to mention a lack of keys) which is avoided with the BOM model.  A (short) primer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17652385/13942986

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH
  cte1 AS (
select p.id p_id,p.code p_code,m2.*
from product p
left join materials m2 on m2.productCode=p.groupCode
where p.code='lp'
),
  cte2 AS (
select p.id p_id,p.code p_code,m1.*
from product p
left join materials m1 on m1.productCode=p.code
where p.code='lp'
)
SELECT cte1.*
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte1.lvl = cte2.lvl
WHERE cte2.lvl IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM cte2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/KqDsDnko